# ng-bootstrap datepicker format

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am using [**ng-bootstrap**](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) datepicker but when I save my form the date gets saved as.

```
date: {
  day: 01,
  month: 12,
  year: 16
}
```

I was hoping I could get it to save as something more like `"2016-11-23T00:39:31.768Z"`

Here is my implementation:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <button class="input-group-btn" (click)="d.toggle()" >
    <md-icon svgSrc="assets/images/calendar-plus.svg" style="cursor: pointer;"></md-icon>
  </button>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="dp" formControlName="due_date" navigation="arrows" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
</div>
```

And form.component:

```
constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      due_date: [''],
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're using ng-bootstrap not ng2-bootstrap (different groups). The code behind it uses the `NgbDateStruct` which is an object `{ day, month, year }`

On submission you'll need to hook in and change the value to something else, like:

```
onSubmit(): {
    let ngbDate = this.form.controls['due_date'].value;
    let myDate = new Date(ngbDate.year, ngbDate.month-1, ngbDate.day);
    let formValues = this.form.value;
    formValues['due_date'] = myDate;
    <...>
    http.post(url, formValues);
}
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

> NgbDateStruct  Interface of the model of the NgbDatepicker and
>   NgbInputDatepicker directives
>
> > Properties
> >
> > day Type: number The day of month, starting at 1
> >
> > month Type: number The month, with default calendar we use ISO 8601: 1=Jan
> >     ... 12=Dec
> >
> > year Type: number The year, for example 2016

Comment: It puzzles me why they decided to invent their own little date object instead of just using a standard Date object. I cant think of any valid reason to do so, and i hate having to write extra code to convert to/from their format.

Comment: For me, using a dedicated Date struct for the picker makes a lot of sense, since the calendar has a day,month,year properties which are absolute numbers (similar to selecting date of birth, you select three numbers). Using the Date object has always been problematic for me for date pickers.

Comment: The sense it makes is limited ... think about comparing two date picker dates ... `date1 > date2` is just impossible with this date structure, but it would easily be possible using the ISO format by default ... or let the user decide which format to use during setup

Answer (score 26):

As @silentsod mentioned, you need to convert the date object that the datepicker uses from the `NgbDateStruct` format into a `string` format. ng-bootstrap provides a function to convert a date in the `NgbDateStruct` format to the `ISO 8601` format (*yyyy-mm-dd*). You do not have to write your own if using that format:

```
import {NgbDateParserFormatter} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

...

constructor(private ngbDateParserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter; ... ) {
    ...
}

...

onSubmit(): {
    let ngbDate = this.form.controls['due_date'].value;
    let myDate = this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(ngbDate); // e.g. myDate = 2017-01-01
    ...
}
```

See: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/ngb-date-parser-formatter.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own method to convert it to DD-MM-YYYY format you require.

Or depending of order of elements in return statement and a separator you can create any other format you wish.

Implementation:

```
formatDate(d: NgbDate): string {
  if (d === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return [
    (d.day < 10 ? ('0' + d.day) : d.day),
    (d.month < 10 ? ('0' + d.month) : d.month),
    d.year
  ].join('-');
}
```