# ng-bootstrap date format starts with zero

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular with ng-bootstrap date component. Datepicker working well. But when I select today date shows as `2018-11-6`.

I need change format like `2018-11-06` (leading zero). How can I change it?

```
  <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="mydate" [(ngModel)]="bankDetailDate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary fa fa-calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2072#issuecomment-366239462) 
And the official [doc](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepicker)

Comment: i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776255/ng-bootstrap-datepicker-format) post from stackoverflow will help you